# Javascript: Read from iframe content?

Tags: javascript

```
function LoadFile() {
  alert("loadfileok");
  var oFrame = document.getElementById("frmFile");
  alert(oFrame);
  var strRawContents = oFrame.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
  alert(strRawContents);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the last alert is not firing?

Everything else works. The only problem seems to be the line before the last?

Comment: Has the frame loaded? Is it on the same domain? Any error messages?

Comment: What error are you getting? (Look at the console of your browser's debugging tool).

Answer (score 2):

If the iframe points to a page on a different site, then this is the "Same Origin Policy" coming into effect:

The essence of the Same Origin policy can be formulated as: windows can work in contexts of each other only if they are from same protocol://domain:port, or, shortly, from same origin.

This is enforced by browsers, to ensure you don't open an iframe pointing to FaceBook, and then adding yourself as a friend, without their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the object you're accessing has the property you think it has. Try this instead:

```
var strRawContents = oFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

You can debug your code in many more ways than just using alert(). For instance, try pressing "F12" (if you're using Chrome or IE) to get the developer tools. This will immensely help with debugging your code.

While we're talking about supported properties, try this next time you want to see what properties an object has available to you:

```
var obj = document.body;
var msg = '';
for( var prop in obj )
    msg += prop + "<br/>";

document.write(msg);
```